# Android Date Picker Fragment can not be set to Custom date

Tags: java, android, datepicker, android-edittext, timepicker

In here 'onClickListner' on 'Image Button' my custom 'DatePickerFragment' is displaying to select the date. Below is the code for

**DatePickerFragment.java**

```
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.DatePicker;

import java.util.Calendar;

/**
 * Created by Admin on 9/4/18.
 */
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
        implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    private onDatePickerListener mListener;
    private boolean future;

    public DatePickerFragment(){

    }

//    public DatePickerFragment(boolean future){
//        this.future=future;
//    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);

        Log.d("DATE_PICKER", " CURRENT_MONTH " + month);

        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), R.style.AppBaseTheme,this, year, month, day);

        if(isFuture() ==false){
            datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
        }
        // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
        return datePickerDialog;
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        // Do something with the date chosen by the user
        callListener(year, month, day);
    }

    public DialogFragment setCallbackListener(onDatePickerListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
        return null;
    }

    private void callListener(int year, int month, int day) {
        if (mListener != null) mListener.onDataSet(year, month, day);
    }

    public boolean isFuture() {
        return future;
    }

    public void setFuture(boolean future) {
        this.future = future;
    }

    public interface onDatePickerListener {
        void onDataSet(int year, int month, int day);
    }
}
```

Then I call this 'Fragment' in my 'MainActivity' to set the date to 'EditText' when click on the 'OK' button from the 'DatePickerFragment'.

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.format.Time;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import com.sample.DatePickerFragment;

public class AddInterestedKarmaActivity extends AppCompatActivity {   

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_interested_karma);

        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        context = this;

        EditText dateEdittext = (Edittext)findViewById(R.id.date_edit);
        setDate(dateEditText);

    }    

    private void setDate(final EditText dateEditText){

            datePickerFragment.setCallbackListener(new DatePickerFragment.onDatePickerListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataSet(int year, int month, int day) {

                    int currentMonth = 0;

                    if (month == 0) {
                        currentMonth = 1;
                    } else if (month == 1) {
                        currentMonth = 2;
                    } else if (month == 2) {
                        currentMonth = 3;
                    } else if (month == 3) {
                        currentMonth = 4;
                    } else if (month == 4) {
                        currentMonth = 5;
                    } else if (month == 5) {
                        currentMonth = 6;
                    } else if (month == 6) {
                        currentMonth = 7;
                    } else if (month == 7) {
                        currentMonth = 8;
                    } else if (month == 8) {
                        currentMonth = 9;
                    } else if (month == 9) {
                        currentMonth = 10;
                    } else if (month == 10) {
                        currentMonth = 11;
                    } else if (month == 11) {
                        currentMonth = 12;
                    } else if (month == 12) {

                    }

                    dateEditText.setText(day + "/" + currentMonth + "/" + year);

                }
            });

        }

        DialogFragment datePicker = datePickerFragment;

        datePicker.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
    }

    private void setTime(final EditText timeEditText){

        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        mHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        mMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(context,
                new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay,
                                          int minute) {

                        String curTime = String.format("%02d:%02d", hourOfDay, minute);
                        timeEditText.setText(curTime);
                    }
                }, mHour, mMinute, false);

        timePickerDialog.show();
    }
}
```

I need to set the Date of 'DatePickerFragmenet' for a custom date (not today). such as set the 'DatePickerFragment' onCreate() to the mentioned above final int y, m, d values that from 'dateEditText'. And also I need to set the custom 'time' to the 'TimePickerDialog' such as 'DatePickerFragment'.

Comment: You are so kind to write these conditions for months. I appreciate your efforts. But you can simply just add 1 into `month`.

Comment: @Amrish Kakadiya, I need to display the EditText.getText().toString() value when DatePickerFragment on the screen at second time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one function in `DatePickerDialog` to set custom date(`updateDate(year_, month_, day_)`)

According to your code you need to make changes in your `DatePickerFragment`
in `onCreateDialog` of `DatePickerFragment` where you are getting `date`, `month` and `year` from calendar, instead of getting that from `Calendar` provide your custom dates.

Updated class is below

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
        implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    private onDatePickerListener mListener;
    private boolean future;
    int day_;
    int month_;
    int year_;
    private DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog;


    public DatePickerFragment() {

    }


    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
//        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
//        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
//        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);

        //    Log.d("DATE_PICKER", " CURRENT_MONTH " + month);

        //   int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), R.style.AppTheme, this, year_, month_, day_);

        if (isFuture() == false) {
            datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
        }
      //  datePickerDialog.updateDate(year_, month_, day_);

        // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
        return datePickerDialog;
    }


    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        // Do something with the date chosen by the user
        callListener(year, month, day);
    }

    public DialogFragment setCallbackListener(onDatePickerListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
        return null;
    }

    private void callListener(int year, int month, int day) {
        if (mListener != null) mListener.onDataSet(year, month, day);
    }

    public boolean isFuture() {
        return future;
    }

    public void setFuture(boolean future) {
        this.future = future;
    }

    public interface onDatePickerListener {
        void onDataSet(int year, int month, int day);
    }
}
```

In your activity, you need to provide custom date. 
Updated Activity is below, you can add your custom date.

```
public class AddInterestedKarmaActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DatePickerFragment datePickerDialog;
    EditText dateEdittext;
    String customDate = "12/12/2007"; //dd/mm/yy

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_interested_karma);


        dateEdittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.date_edit);
        //  setDate(dateEditText);


        datePickerDialog = new DatePickerFragment();
        datePickerDialog.day_ = getDay();
        datePickerDialog.month_ = getMonth();
        datePickerDialog.year_ = getYear();

        datePickerDialog.setCallbackListener(new DatePickerFragment.onDatePickerListener() {
                                                 @Override
                                                 public void onDataSet(int year, int month, int day) {
                                                     month = month + 1;
                                                     dateEdittext.setText(day + "/" + month + "/" + year);

                                                 }
                                             }
        );

        datePickerDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");

    }

    private int getYear() {
        return Integer.parseInt(changeDateFormat(customDate, "MM/dd/yyyy", "YYYY"));

    }

    private int getMonth() {
        return Integer.parseInt(changeDateFormat(customDate, "MM/dd/yyyy", "MM")) - 1;  //substract one from month because month gets start from 0 in Calendar.

    }

    private int getDay() {
        return Integer.parseInt(changeDateFormat(customDate, "MM/dd/yyyy", "dd"));
    }


    public String changeDateFormat(String dateString, String sourceDateFormat, String targetDateFormat) {
        if (dateString == null || dateString.isEmpty())
            return "";

        SimpleDateFormat inputDateFromat = new SimpleDateFormat(sourceDateFormat, Locale.US);
        Date date = new Date();

        try {
            date = inputDateFromat.parse(dateString);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        SimpleDateFormat outputDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(targetDateFormat, Locale.US);

        return outputDateFormat.format(date);
    }


}
```

Comment: I did the changes, but In Activity datePickerDialog.year_ = getYear is displaying an error as same as month and date. Therefore I can't set a date. Then datePickerDialog onCreate displays nothing selected.

Comment: Thanks for the effort to give me a solution. Mainly I need to set custom date to datePickerDialog. Because I retrieve a date from database and assign it to EditText. After that I need to display that date on DatePickerDialog. datePickerDialog.day_ = getDay();
        datePickerDialog.month_ = getMonth();
        datePickerDialog.year_ = getYear(); are the lines that display errors.

Comment: In AddInterestedKarmaActivity i have taken a variable customDate, you can assign your date  from database to this variable. Regarding the errors you are getting,  getDay(), getMonth() and getYear() are methods i have created in the same activity. you just need to copy these two classes and paste in your code. If still any error getting then let me know ill help you.

Comment: Actually, the error is came from DatePickerFragment, because of didn't initiate date veriables such as public int getDay_() {
        return day_;
    }

    public void setDay_(int day_) {
        this.day_ = day_;
    }

    public int getMonth_() {
        return month_;
    }

    public void setMonth_(int month_) {
        this.month_ = month_;
    }

    public int getYear_() {
        return year_;
    }

    public void setYear_(int year_) {
        this.year_ = year_;
    } Now I corrected that issue and now It's working perfectly. Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: did you make above changes in your DatePickerFragment fragment?